# Disable closing button on opened modal dialogs Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

Say I open a dialog like this:

```
        Login login = new Login();
        if(login.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.OK)
            Application.Exit();
```

Now, login form has a close button in the menu by standard, and closing it seem to either return DialogResult.OK or no dialogresult at all and my application continues without repercussions. How to solve that problem?

Comment: Closing a form with X-button should result in DialogResult.Cancel. I guess you're setting it to OK somewhere in the code. Can you show what's in `Login`?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I have Login show up in my MainForm constructor, maybe that's not helping? The dialog only returns DialogResult.OK upon one event callback, not changing it anywhere else.

Comment: That's not normal... then you can set DialogResult to Cancel in the constructor of the form.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally changed the form's property instead of button's? I mean when you created the OK button. Check in the form designer.

Comment: Oh well, not sure what was up. I moved handling the DialogResult from MainForm constructor to FormClosed callback of Login and fixed it this way. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ControlBox` property to false.

Comment: Rightclicking on the taskbar and hitting close also closes the dialog and lets the code pass through. What do?